# How do I remove horizontal lines from Mime Message?

Tags: python, mime-message, mime-mail

Noob, creating his first dynamic webpage, where a user can enter a message, along with their first and last name, email and phone number. I care most about the message, which I intend to forward via email, along with the other information, if provided. I have written a simple python script (site will be Flask, python and HTML), but it is inserting an unwanted horizontal line between each output, i.e.

Dear Bob

---

Message contents go here

---

first name

---

My goal is to have the outgoing message resemble an actual email, i.e. like above, but without the horizontal lines. I found most of the below code online, which is largely working. Simple answers that I can understand are preferred to clever ones I cannot (I'm a Noob).

```
def to_mail(first, last, phone, email, User_Complaint, addressed_to):
    # E mail account details
    my_sending_email = 'testing@gmail.com'
    sending_email_password = 'pass'

    # set up the SMTP server
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(my_sending_email, sending_email_password)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['Subject'] = 'Reporting an Issue With the Courts'
    msg['From'] = my_sending_email
    msg['To'] = addressed_to

    # Body of Email
    intro = MIMEText("Dear Leader")
    message_contents = MIMEText(User_Complaint)

    # use of .attach appears to insert the horizontal line
    msg.attach(intro)
    msg.attach(message_contents)

    # Party's Contact Info to append at bottom of email
    msg.attach(MIMEText(first + last))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(phone))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(email))

    s.send_message(msg)
    del msg

    s.quit()
```

I just want to generate normal looking email content in the message body, i.e.

"Dear Leader,

I really like your hair. I'm your biggest fan.

(each biographic entry following should be on its own newline, but this automatically puts it on one line)
Stan Lee\n
stan@lee.com\n
647-647-1234"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a single msg.attach to avoid multiple horizontal lines:

```
# Body of Email
text = "Dear Leader\n" + User_Complaint + "\n" + phone + "\n" + email
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Dear Leader<br>
       I really like your hair. I'm your biggest fan.<br>
       (each biographic entry following should be on 
its own newline, but this automatically puts it on one line)
Stan Lee\n stan@lee.com\n 647-647-1234.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

s.send_message(msg)
del msg
s.quit()
```

It's more better to define the mail body inside html an txt files and render this files using jinja2 template engine. So you need to create two files:

mail.text

```
Dear Bob!\n
{{ User_Complaint }}\n
{{ phone }} \n
{{ email }}
```

mail.html

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
    Dear Bob!<br/>
    {{ User_Complaint }}<br/>
    {{ phone }}<br/>
    {{ email }}
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And to_mail function will be similar to this:

```
from flask import render_template
def to_mail(first, last, phone, email, User_Complaint, addressed_to):

    # The old code
    #...
    # Body of Email
    part1 = render_template("mail.txt",
    User_Complaint = User_Complaint,
    email=email, phone=phone)

    part2 = render_template("mail.html",
    User_Complaint = User_Complaint,
    email=email, phone=phone)

    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    s.send_message(msg)
    del msg
    s.quit()
```

It's not bad idea to use [flask-mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) to send mail.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Assili, I was able to fix my code based on your suggestion with the following small tweaks.

```
#Body of Email

text = intro + '\n' + '\n'  + message_contents + '\n' + '\n' + first + '' + last + '\n' + phone + '\n' + email 

msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
```